# rxJava toBlockin() method not found

Tags: java, rx-java

I am following some article on rxJava and following code:

```
 Observable
            .interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .take(5)
            .toBlocking() // No such method!
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

gives an error that toBlocking is not found. In my build.gradle I have:

implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.9"

Why there is no toBlocking method? Am I using wrong dependency? Its clearly available in docs:

http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#toBlocking()

Answer (score 0):

It appears I should use following code:

```
    Observable
            .interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .take(5)
            .blockingForEach(System.out::println);
```

and this documentation:

https://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html

I was reading some very old book, from June 2015

Comment: Indeed. See https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#operator-differences (search for toBlocking).